# reusable application for django site wide announcements that displays a message only once per user

Tags: python, django, code-reuse, pinax

I want to show various messages to registered users only once in my django application. I found [django-announcements](http://github.com/pinax/django-announcements/)  which seemed to do what I want - but I found in testing it marks messages as read by using a session variable, which disappears if the user logs out. This means a message is shown again to a user if they dismiss it when logged in, log out, and then log in again.

I wondered if anyone know of an application that I might be able to use here without re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [django-notification](http://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/). It is used by pinax, there it seems to work like what you are searching for. At least it saves the status in the db.

### edit

Response to the comment

from the [docs](http://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/blob/master/docs/usage.txt):

```
notification.send([to_user], "friends_invite", {"from_user": from_user})
```

so this should work:

```
notification.send(Users.objects.all(), "friends_invite", {"from_user": from_user})
```

and if a queryset isnt right:

```
notification.send([u for u in Users.objects.all()], "friends_invite", {"from_user": from_user})
```

Comment: I'm using django-notification but it unfortunately didnt seem to handle notifications to _all_ users.

Comment: the list comprehension in the last example could more easily and clearly be written as `list(Users.objects.all())` instead of `[u for u in Users.objects.all()]`.

Comment: what is more clearly and easily is matter of taste, I think. But your comment is a good hint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Messages Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/messages/) in Django 1.3? In Django <=1.2 it was a simple model so you could do:

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    user.message_set.create(message="some text")
```

and this would be rendered in the template, and dismissed as soon as the next page is loaded (it's what Django admin uses). It has changed a bit in 1.3, but it might be handy, but not 'dismissable' in the way that maybe you want.